# jenkins rebuilder stores passwords

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use Jenkins parameterized jobs with password parameter, and also using rebuilder.
when I use Jenkins rebuilder on parameterized jobs, the password parameter is also stored, as well as the previous

Is there a way to prevent Jenkins rebuilder store passwords type parameters?

I do make a statement here - this is not Jenkins secret store parameter - rather Jenkins passwords build parameter, but this is not less sensitive...

Tnx
autoteam

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hey did'nt manage to find an image for that, but this is the password parameter of Jenkins for parameterized job