# How can I configure the Jenkins Rebuilder plugin to not remember passwords?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We would like the Jenkins Rebuilder plugin to not remember passwords.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. I did look at the similar [jenkins rebuilder stores passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72351276/jenkins-rebuilder-stores-passwords) question, but it doesn't have an answer.

A colleague of mine pointed out that the Rebuilder plugin source has a `RebuildConfiguration` class with a `rememberPasswordEnabled` field - see the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/rebuild/com/sonyericsson/rebuild/RebuildConfiguration.html) and [source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rebuild-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/rebuild/RebuildConfiguration.java). Is the `rememberPasswordEnabled` configuration actually used? Is there a way to configure `rememberPasswordEnabled` on an installed and enabled Rebuilder plugin?

**Update**: Also, when I bring up the configuration for my pipeline, I see a Rebuild options section:

[image]

But it doesn't contain an option for remembering passwords.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found the Rebuild plugin remember password option.  It's under **Dashboard** > **Manage Jenkins** > ***System***:

[image]

Once we disabled this option, the Rebuild plugin no longer remembers passwords on rebuild.